# Convert function with byte[] from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

There is original C# code for my function:
Them works like a charm, and i will convert them to C++

```
    public static byte[] EncryptBlock(byte[] filebuffer)
    {
        int a, i, j, k, tmp;
        int[] key, box;
        byte[] cipher;

        key = new int[KeyBoxLength];
        box = new int[KeyBoxLength];
        cipher = new byte[filebuffer.Length];

        for (i = 0; i < KeyBoxLength; i++)
        {
            key[i] = XorContentLock[i % XorContentLock.Length];
            box[i] = i;
        }
        for (j = i = 0; i < KeyBoxLength; i++)
        {
            j = (j + box[i] + key[i]) % 256;
            tmp = box[i];
            box[i] = box[j];
            box[j] = tmp;
        }
        for (a = j = i = 0; i < filebuffer.Length; i++)
        {
            a++;
            a %= KeyBoxLength;
            j += box[a];
            j %= KeyBoxLength;
            tmp = box[a];
            box[a] = box[j];
            box[j] = tmp;
            k = box[((box[a] + box[j]) % KeyBoxLength)];
            cipher[i] = (byte)(filebuffer[i] ^ k);
        }
        return cipher;
    }
```

And that is how them looks on C++, but i dont have idea, why i've got those errors.

```
std::string Conversion::EncryptBlock(std::string& buffer)
{
    int32 a, i, j, k, tmp;
    int key[256];
    int box[256];
    BYTE* cipher = new BYTE[buffer.length];
    for (i = 0; i < KeyBoxLength; i++)
    {
        key[i] = XorFileLock[i % 16];
        box[i] = i;
    }
    for (j = i = 0; i < KeyBoxLength; i++)
    {
        j = (j + box[i] + key[i]) % 256;
        tmp = box[i];
        box[i] = box[j];
        box[j] = tmp;
    }
    for (a = j = i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
    {
        a++;
        a %= KeyBoxLength;
        j += box[a];
        j %= KeyBoxLength;
        tmp = box[a];
        box[a] = box[j];
        box[j] = tmp;
        k = box[((box[a] + box[j]) % KeyBoxLength)];
        cipher[i] = (byte)(buffer[i] ^ k);
    }
    std::string ret(reinterpret_cast< char const* >(cipher));
    delete[] cipher;

    return ret;
}
```

And when i compile that, i've got this:

[image]

I already got some articles for how convert them, and assign dynamically a byte array. But in my case, seems it's does not work, and i cant understand how to convert those working C# code into C++. Did not got how to resolve C# byte[] into unsigned* int C++, with conversion of those array to std::string after.

Well, what i am doing wrong there? And explain please, why? And how it's should be?
Another example:
[image]

Comment: I've already read those, and try, but they tell me "expression must have a constant value". I am totally disappointed.

Comment: @EamonnMcEvoy C++ doesn't have variable length arrays.  It does have `std::vector` though.

Comment: Code above, "should" works, cuz i am not able to see any error (i've did all the same as on tutorials), and also, there is no anything on IntelliTrace, without any red-lines. Just simple does not compiles... Screen above. Dunno how to convert those...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string::length` is a method, not a constant.  The error you're seeing is telling you you can't convert from "pointer to member function of `std::string`" to `unsigned int`.  You're missing a pair of parenthesis:

```
BYTE* cipher = new BYTE[buffer.length()];
                                  // ^^ Here
```

Unrelated to your problem, you should use `std::vector<BYTE>` instead of managing your own raw arrays.  You can change the declaration of `cipher` to

```
std::vector<BYTE> cipher(buffer.length());
```

and change the declaration of `ret` to

```
std::string ret(cipher.begin(), cipher.end());
```

Then you don't have to remember to `delete[] cipher`.  There's no real reason to copy `cipher` to `ret` though, you could just declare `cipher` as `std::string cipher(buffer.length(), '\0');` and `return cipher;` directly.

Comment: Oh, thanks for explain those!

Comment: @HappyDay If the answer helped you solve your problem/error, please mark it as the Right Answer, so others who read your question or have the same problem will know where to look.